# Can someone Tell me how can i get Input from jtf1 and jtf2 and Display the output on jtf3?

Tags: java

```
 import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    class Event implements ActionListener{
      JButton jb1;
       void setGui()
         {

      JFrame x=new JFrame("CALCULATOR");
       x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       x.setSize(800,800);
       x.setVisible(true);  

      Container c=x.getContentPane();
      c.setLayout(null);
      c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JLabel jl1=new JLabel("NUMBER 1");
      jl1.setSize(100,50);
      jl1.setLocation(0,0);
      jl1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
      c.add(jl1);

      JLabel jl2=new JLabel("NUMBER 2");
      jl2.setSize(100,50);
      jl2.setLocation(0,150);
      jl2.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
      c.add(jl2);

     JLabel jl3=new JLabel("ANSWER");
      jl3.setSize(100,50);
      jl3.setLocation(0,400);
      jl3.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
      c.add(jl3);

     JTextField jtf1=new JTextField();
      jtf1.setSize(100,50);
      jtf1.setLocation(80,0);
      jtf1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      c.add(jtf1);

    JTextField jtf2=new JTextField();
      jtf2.setSize(100,50);
      jtf2.setLocation(80,150);
      jtf2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      c.add(jtf2);

      JTextField jtf3=new JTextField();
      jtf3.setSize(100,50);
      jtf3.setLocation(80,400);
      jtf3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      c.add(jtf3);

      jb1=new JButton("ADD");
      jb1.setSize(100,100);
      jb1.setLocation(300,500);
      jb1.setBackground(Color.RED);
      c.add(jb1);

     JButton jb2=new JButton("MULTIPLY");
      jb2.setSize(100,100);
      jb2.setLocation(450,500);
      jb2.setBackground(Color.RED);
      c.add(jb2);

          jb1.addActionListener(this);
          jb2.addActionListener(this);
         }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent q)
     {  if(q.getSource()==jb1)(jb1=o,jb2=n)
             { 

             }            
     }
}

      class DX
 {


    public static void main(String args[])
    {


       Event et=new Event();
       et.setGui();
      }

    }
```

//This is the Java code i wrote Need a Bit of help with this. Thank you 
//https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-P9R0IIsAcz8/Vk6QQSs63SI/AAAAAAAAABk/d0q1jfpm9cE/w908-h809-no/fffffffff.PNG
//https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-5yjWTnQ8X8o/Vk6QVfroQtI/AAAAAAAAAB8/17k1HnHGmlc/w869-h629-no/hhhh.PNG

Comment: It seems, you should go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html) instead of the SO.

Comment: Just before you start using the `TextField`

Comment: Do never post code in form of a picture on SO! Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit too Detailed i can't understand it Properly can you tell me how to add it in to my Code ?

Comment: I Put both Code and the Picture Not only the Picture

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Refer this, just copy below code to you machine and Run.
I hope it's what you want.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DX {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Event et=new Event();
        et.setGui();
    }
}

class Event implements ActionListener{
    JButton jb1;
    JTextField jtf1;
    JTextField jtf2;
    JTextField jtf3;
    void setGui()
    {

        JFrame x=new JFrame("CALCULATOR");
        x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        x.setSize(800,800);
        x.setVisible(true);  

        Container c=x.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JLabel jl1=new JLabel("NUMBER 1");
        jl1.setSize(100,50);
        jl1.setLocation(0,0);
        jl1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        c.add(jl1);

        JLabel jl2=new JLabel("NUMBER 2");
        jl2.setSize(100,50);
        jl2.setLocation(0,150);
        jl2.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        c.add(jl2);

        JLabel jl3=new JLabel("ANSWER");
        jl3.setSize(100,50);
        jl3.setLocation(0,400);
        jl3.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        c.add(jl3);

         jtf1=new JTextField();
        jtf1.setSize(100,50);
        jtf1.setLocation(80,0);
        jtf1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        c.add(jtf1);

         jtf2=new JTextField();
        jtf2.setSize(100,50);
        jtf2.setLocation(80,150);
        jtf2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        c.add(jtf2);

        jtf3=new JTextField();
        jtf3.setSize(100,50);
        jtf3.setLocation(80,400);
        jtf3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        c.add(jtf3);

        jb1=new JButton("ADD");
        jb1.setSize(100,100);
        jb1.setLocation(300,500);
        jb1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        c.add(jb1);

        JButton jb2=new JButton("MULTIPLY");
        jb2.setSize(100,100);
        jb2.setLocation(450,500);
        jb2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        c.add(jb2);

        jb1.addActionListener(this);
        jb2.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent q)
    { 
        System.out.println(q.getActionCommand()); 

        if((jtf1.getText() != null && jtf1.getText().length() > 0) && (jtf2.getText() != null && jtf2.getText().length() > 0)){
            try {

                int val1 = Integer.parseInt(jtf1.getText()) ;
                int val2 = Integer.parseInt(jtf2.getText()) ;

                if("MULTIPLY".equals(q.getActionCommand())){
                    int ans = (val1*val2);
                    jtf3.setText(ans+"");
                }else if("ADD".equals(q.getActionCommand())){
                    int ans = (val1+val2);
                    jtf3.setText(ans+"");
                }  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                jtf1.setText("");
                jtf2.setText("");
                jtf3.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Valid Value", "Error", 0);
            }
        }else{
            jtf1.setText("");
            jtf2.setText("");
            jtf3.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Text First", "Error", 0);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Yes That is What i Wanted to Do. Thank you Very Much ^^